# error: Abort trap: 6 (in target 'Project-Name' from project 'Project-Name') in XCode 12

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode12

My project source code working fine in **XCode-11** but when I'm trying to run my project in **XCode-12** getting  `error: Abort trap: 6 (in target 'Cyber-Call' from project 'Cyber-Call')`.

- Build error log

```
/Users/inextrix/MyApps/Charles Project/ChatAndAddOns/ZapDial/IOS/MQTT Chat Module/Resources/External Functional Utilities/PopupKit/PopupView.h:205:63: warning: imported declaration 'forEachPopupDoBlock:' could not be mapped to 'UIView.forEachPopup(handle:)'
- (void)forEachPopupDoBlock:(void (^)(PopupView *popup))block NS_SWIFT_NAME(UIView.forEachPopup(handle:));
                                                              ^
<unknown>:0: error: fatal error encountered while reading from module 'ZapDial'; please file a bug report with your project and the crash log
<unknown>:0: note: module 'ZapDial' full misc version is '5.3(4.2)/Apple Swift version 5.3 (swiftlang-1200.0.29.2 clang-1200.0.30.1)'

*** DESERIALIZATION FAILURE (please include this section in any bug report) ***
top-level value not found
Cross-reference to module 'JSQMessagesViewController'
... JSQMessageMediaData

1.  Apple Swift version 5.3 (swiftlang-1200.0.29.2 clang-1200.0.30.1)
2.  Contents of /var/folders/rc/br1cwpj14c51mrpmd78p38zr0000gn/T/inputs-5cfe1d:
---
/Users/inextrix/MyApps/Charles Project/ChatAndAddOns/ZapDial/IOS/DerivedData/Cyber-Call/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Cyber-Call.build/Debug-iphoneos/Cyber-Call.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SelectNetworkTableViewController~partial.swiftmodule
/Users/inextrix/MyApps/Charles Project/ChatAndAddOns/ZapDial/IOS/DerivedData/Cyber-Call/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Cyber-Call.build/Debug-iphoneos/Cyber-Call.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UIImage+Gif-ad999f89e29c7457d96d3e73509f6404384df406a922a7cce2d053302ce82bc3~partial.swiftmodule
/Users/inextrix/MyApps/Charles Project/ChatAndAddOns/ZapDial/IOS/DerivedData/Cyber-Call/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Cyber-Call.build/Debug-iphoneos/Cyber-Call.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ContactDetailsScreenVC~partial.swiftmodule
/Users/inextrix/MyApps/Charles Project/ChatAndAddOns/ZapDial/IOS/DerivedData/Cyber-Call/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Cyber-Call.build/Debug-iphoneos/Cyber-Call.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AudioURLTrack~partial.swiftmodule

---
3.  While evaluating request ExecuteSILPipelineRequest(Run pipelines { Mandatory Combines, Serialization, Rest of Onone } on SIL for ZapDial.ZapDial)
4.  While loading conformances for 'RepliedSentImageMediaItem' (in module 'ZapDial')
0  swift                    0x00000001058bd865 llvm::sys::PrintStackTrace(llvm::raw_ostream&) + 37
1  swift                    0x00000001058bc865 llvm::sys::RunSignalHandlers() + 85
2  swift                    0x00000001058bde1f SignalHandler(int) + 111
3  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x00007fff6bb325fd _sigtramp + 29
4  libsystem_platform.dylib 0x000000010d5c4668 _sigtramp + 18446603343228379272
5  libsystem_c.dylib        0x00007fff6ba08808 abort + 120
6  swift                    0x0000000101e9607c swift::ModuleFile::fatal(llvm::Error) + 2348
7  swift                    0x0000000101eb29b5 swift::ModuleFile::loadAllConformances(swift::Decl const*, unsigned long long, llvm::SmallVectorImpl<swift::ProtocolConformance*>&) + 805
8  swift                    0x0000000102629d6c swift::ConformanceLookupTable::updateLookupTable(swift::NominalTypeDecl*, swift::ConformanceLookupTable::ConformanceStage) + 300
9  swift                    0x0000000102629e7f swift::ConformanceLookupTable::updateLookupTable(swift::NominalTypeDecl*, swift::ConformanceLookupTable::ConformanceStage) + 575
10 swift                    0x0000000102629f94 swift::ConformanceLookupTable::updateLookupTable(swift::NominalTypeDecl*, swift::ConformanceLookupTable::ConformanceStage) + 852
11 swift                    0x000000010275c7a9 swift::NominalTypeDecl::getAllProtocols() const + 73
12 swift                    0x0000000101a29d3c (anonymous namespace)::NominalTypeWalker::walkToDeclPre(swift::Decl*) + 60
13 swift                    0x00000001025fff1d (anonymous namespace)::Traversal::doIt(swift::Decl*) + 189
14 swift                    0x0000000101a29210 swift::ProtocolConformanceAnalysis::init() + 240
15 swift                    0x0000000101bc3ddf swift::SILPassManager::SILPassManager(swift::SILModule*, bool, swift::irgen::IRGenModule*) + 2623
16 swift                    0x0000000101bdc6d1 swift::SimpleRequest<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest, std::__1::tuple<> (swift::SILPipelineExecutionDescriptor), (swift::RequestFlags)1>::evaluateRequest(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&, swift::Evaluator&) + 49
17 swift                    0x0000000101bcac35 llvm::Expected<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest::OutputType> swift::Evaluator::getResultUncached<swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest>(swift::ExecuteSILPipelineRequest const&) + 1045
18 swift                    0x0000000101bce076 swift::runSILPassesForOnone(swift::SILModule&) + 166
19 swift                    0x00000001015618b4 swift::CompilerInstance::performSILProcessing(swift::SILModule*) + 772
20 swift                    0x0000000101434688 performCompileStepsPostSILGen(swift::CompilerInstance&, swift::CompilerInvocation const&, std::__1::unique_ptr<swift::SILModule, std::__1::default_delete<swift::SILModule> >, llvm::PointerUnion<swift::ModuleDecl*, swift::SourceFile*>, swift::PrimarySpecificPaths const&, int&, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 1288
21 swift                    0x0000000101424ae0 swift::performFrontend(llvm::ArrayRef<char const*>, char const*, void*, swift::FrontendObserver*) + 21152
22 swift                    0x00000001013a5c07 main + 1255
23 libdyld.dylib            0x00007fff6b939cc9 start + 1
24 libdyld.dylib            0x0000000000000133 start + 18446603338711327851
error: Abort trap: 6 (in target 'Cyber-Call' from project 'Cyber-Call')
```